# How to solve these equations using Cramer's rule?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$a,b,x,y,z \in I \ $  and are not equal to zero

$x+ay+z=3$

$2x+y+bz=1$

$3x+y+3z=2$

find $ \ 2x-3y+2z+3ab$

I started with , $D=2-(6a+b)+3ab$

$D_{x} = 8-3(a+b)+2ab$ ,$\ \ D_{y} = 7b-14$ ,$\ \ D_{z} = -a-2$

Then, $x= \frac{D_{x}}{D}$ $\ \ y= \frac{D_{y}}{D}$ $z= \frac{D_{z}}{D} $ and get stuck because I don't know how  to  solve  for integer solutions.

Is it possible to find out any variable $a,b,x,y,z$ ?

Thanks for any help. Sorry for my mistake in english.

Answer (score 2):

You have $D = (b-2)(3a-1)$ and $D_y = 7(b-2)$. If $a, y$ are integers and if $b\not= 2$, it means that $3a -1 | 7$, which leaves only $a=-2, y=-1$ or $a=0, y=-7$.